# Normalizer of a subgroup of prime index

Tags: abstract-algebra

I need help with this problem.

If H is a subgroup of prime index in a finite group G, show that either N(H)=G or N(H) = H.

So as H has prime index it means it is cyclic. Also we have that p=ord(H) | ord(N) | ord(G). So we should have ord(N)= $k_1$p and ord(G)= $k_2$ord(N)=$k_1k_2$p. So we have to show that either $k_1$=1 or $k_2$=1. This is what I got by now. But I don't know what to do next

Comment: Your first statement is incorrect. A subgroup of prime order is cyclic, but your subgroup is of prime index.

Comment: Indeed, there seems to be some confusion between "prime order" and "prime index" (note that the title doesn't match the problem).

Answer (score 2):

The idea is that we must have $H < \operatorname{N}(H) < G$. This is because $H$ is a subgroup, so it's closed, and at least the elements of $H$ conjugate into $H$. Since $H$ has prime index $p$, there can be no subgroup properly between $H$ and $G$. If $\operatorname{N}(H)$ were properly between $H$ and $G$, its index in $G$ would have to divide $p$. So we must have either $\operatorname{N}(H) = G$ or $\operatorname{N}(H) = H$.